# Why does d3.json return "null"?

Tags: javascript, python, json, d3.js, networkx

I have two JSON files, which are node-link dumps from NetworkX.

One is called `force2.json`. The other is called `arcage.json`. The data inside there are essentially equivalent. `force2.json` contains more node-links than `arcage.json`, but both were dumped by NetworkX's

```
json_graph.node_link_data(graph)
```

followed by

```
json.dump(jsongraph, open('viz/agearc.json','w')) #(or force2.json)
```

In my javascript file, when I use:

```
d3.json('force2.json', function(d) {
    console.log(d) })
```

I can inspect the graph object properly.

However, when I do:

```
d3.json('arcage.json', function(d) {
    console.log(d) })
```

I get a `null` return. I cannot explain why - might someone be able to help me with this please?

For the record, `arcage.json` is an undirected graph, and `force2.json` is a directed graph. The two graphs have essentially identical node-link information, except that `arcage.json` has an additional text property in the nodes, and an additional text property in the links, which did not give an error when doing the serialization dump from NetworkX.

I have also checked the inter-webs for help, and found that I need to have an HTTP server running. I am doing that (`python -m http.server` in the working directory), and I am working locally only.

EDIT:

The raw data are available here:

- arcage: www.ericmajinglong.com/science/minto_america/arcage.json
- force2: www.ericmajinglong.com/science/minto_america/force2.json

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? It sounds like one file is in the place where you expect it to be, the other one isn't.

Comment: And you are sure that `arcage.json` contains the expected data? Unrelated to the problem, but maybe relevant to you (disclaimer: I work on this): http://jsnetworkx.org/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, I'm not getting any error messages. Both files are in the same directory. I am only getting a "null" return.

Comment: @FelixKling: I have inspected the JSON files. They contain influenza virus isolate names and other metadata for which when I compare the two, the metadata are identical with the exception of the additional string fields in arcage.json.

Comment: What happens if you try to access the file directly in the browser (via the URL)?

Comment: Loads with no problems.

Comment: I am happy to provide the two JSON files to you guys if you can help me with them!

Comment: Oh. Check the signature of the callback function: `d3.json("path/to/file.json", function(error, json) {` . https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61358/discussion-between-ericmjl-and-felix-kling).

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the culprit is having invalid JSON present. I had a `NaN` value present in my data.

To all the newbies like me out there - if you have an error like mine, please don't forget to check for `NaN`, and impute an appropriate value inside! I hope this saves you the trouble!